# ResultSet instance is not null, but next() call throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, jdbc, nullpointerexception

I have two cursors which are used to display details in UI.

```
headerCur = (ResultSet) cstmt.getObject(4);
serialCur = (ResultSet) cstmt.getObject(5);
```

When the user enters a wrong value, it goes to `serialCur.next()`.

```
while (serialCur.next()) {
    // ...
}
```

However, it throws a `NullPointerException`.

I have logged and found that the `serialCur` is not null, but the `next()` call throws null pointer exception anyway.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: while(serialCur.hasNext())

Comment: can you provide the full stacktrace in your question. and the coding as well

Comment: @MaxG there is no `hasNext()` on a `ResultSet` - [`next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next--) is the right one to be using here

Comment: @JonK you're right... it means that the result set throws exception. so try catch block?

Comment: How to check for Not null

Comment: try go to loop if ResultSet has a value .use if `(resultSet.isBeforeFirst() ) {  `

Comment: I tried still is not working

Comment: Stacktrace or didn't happen

Answer (score -2):

Use

```
 while (serialCur.isBeforeFirst() ) {
// ...
}
```

OR

```
if(serialCur.isBeforeFirst()) {
while (serialCur.next() ) {
// ...
} 
}
```

to check if result set has a value